# Using a 32-bit library in a 64-bit app

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture, 64-bit, zbar-sdk

I have my project set up to run as 64-bit on supporting devices, and 32-bit otherwise. `ZBarSDK` is giving me an issue though. I get the error `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`.

Doing a `lipo -info` on the library file results in: `armv6 armv7 i386`

Is there a way to still compile my project for 64-bit and include this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. 32-bit code cannot call 64-bit code and vice versa.